# How to use a tempfile for certificate based authentication?

Tags: python, client-certificates, temporary-files, requests-oauthlib

I want to fetch an OAuth token using client credentials with an X.509 certificate. I am using [requests-oauthlib](https://pypi.org/project/requests-oauthlib/) with the [OAuth2 backend application flow](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#backend-application-flow). I'm getting the certificate and key at runtime from the framework I'm running in as strings not as file paths. Also I need to override the `fetch_token()` method of the library's `OAuth2Session` class to enable use of certificates because that's not yet available in the current 1.3.0 release.

The following works fine (with `CertSession` being my cert-enabled version of `OAuth2Session`):

```py
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from .sessions import CertSession

# ... code to obtain client credentials (client_id, cert, key) from framework...

client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
session = CertSession(client=client)
token = None

with open('cert_file.pem', 'w') as cert_file:
    cert_file.write(cert)
    
with open('key_file.pem', 'w') as key_file:
    key_file.write(key)

try:
    token = session.fetch_token(token_url=token_url, include_client_id=True, cert=(cert_file.name, key_file.name))
    print(token)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

However, I feel a bit uncomfortable with using plain old files for storing the certificate files. So I was trying to do the same using [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html):

```py
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from .sessions import CertSession
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

# ... code to obtain client credentials (client_id, cert, key) from framework...

client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
session = CertSession(client=client)
token = None

cert_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', suffix='.pem')
cert_file.write(cert)
cert_file.flush()

key_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', suffix='.pem')
key_file.write(key)
key_file.flush()

try:
    token = session.fetch_token(token_url=token_url, include_client_id=True, cert=(cert_file.name, key_file.name))
    print(token)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

which gives me
`('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: It works with tempfiles if I open them with `delete=False` but that kinda defeats the purpose of using tempfiles in the first place, doesn't it?

Comment: I never found out the reason why this sort of thing happens, but whenever I encounter issues with `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`, I switch to writing to normal files located inside of a `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory`. Does that work for you?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), it seems like you can't open the `NamedTemporaryFile` again on Windows while the file is still open. Are you on a Windows machine?

Comment: @rchome, yes am on Windows, and I'll try with normal files inside a `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory`.

Comment: @rchome, indeed putting normal files inside a temp directory works for me, so thanks again. Strange though, that it also works with `delete=False` given the documentation you pointed out. The behavior seems a bit inconsistent...